# Data filtering for a specific situation

Tags: r, excel

| Species | Variable1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 7.2 |
| 3 | NA |
| 4 | 7.4 |
| 4 | 7.5 |
| 5 | 7.0 |
| 5 | 7.8 |
| 6 | 7.0 |
| 6 | 8.0 |
| 7 | 8.9 |
| 7 | 9.1 |
| 8 | 9.2 |
| 8 | 9.4 |

There are groups from 3 to 8 in a variable named "Type". In another variable, there are numerical data. For example, for Type 3, there are 2 observations in the numerical variable and 2 observations for the other variables (for variable2 to variable 132). However, in another numerical variable, there is only 1 observation for Type 3 instead of 2, which is expected for every group. I want to remove the observations with the value of 1 in the numerical variable for the specified Type and save the modified dataset.

Comment: Can you please post an expected output? Also, there's no "Type".

Comment: If you’re working with two data frames, then we need examples of both types. Also you say a value of 1 but from context it sounds like you mean a count of 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to guess what you want. I understand that you only want to keep the data that has 2 entries and no missing value.

DATA

```
df <- data.frame(
  species = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8),
  variable1 = c(7.2, NA, 7.4, 7.5, 7.0, 7.8, 7.0, 8.0, 8.9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.4)
)
```

Filtering

```
library(tidyverse)

filtered <- df %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  filter(n() == 2 & !any(is.na(variable1))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

RESULT

| Species | Variable1 |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 7.4 |
| 4 | 7.5 |
| 5 | 7.0 |
| 5 | 7.8 |
| 6 | 7.0 |
| 6 | 8.0 |
| 7 | 8.9 |
| 7 | 9.1 |
| 8 | 9.2 |
| 8 | 9.4 |